# Is it possible to push out a Flutter app over Intune without going through the Google Play Store?

Tags: networking, android, microsoft-intune

I made a flutter app and our team wants to push it out using Intune to a company owned Honeywell scanner. This scanner is running Android 11. If this works, we will be pushing this out to around 50 scanners.

Is it possible to not only deploy the app using Intune but also push out upgrades remotely, all while avoiding the Google Play Store? I know that Google provides a way to list your app as private, but I just don't see a reason to go through all of that work when this is all going to happen in our in-house wifi network, i.e. there will be no need to push this out to any other device that is not connected to our network.

Answer (score 0):

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/apps-add-android-for-work#managed-google-play-private-lob-apps**

Looks like the MS recommended way takes 10 minutes.

> 1. Directly in the Microsoft Intune admin center - This allows you
>    to add LOB apps by submitting just the app APK and a title, directly
>    within Intune. This method does not require you to have a Google
>    developer account and does not require you to pay the fee to register
>    with Google as a developer. This method is simpler and has a
>    significantly reduced number of steps, and makes LOB apps available
>    for management **in as little as ten minutes**.
> 2. In the Google Play Developer Console - If you have a Google developer account or want to configure advanced distribution features
>    that are only available in the Google Play Developer Console (like
>    adding additional app screenshots), you can use the Google Play
>    Developer Console.

Comment: I'm told by my helpdesk team that LOB apps require Android device administrator, but this has been superseded by Android Enterprise. And if you use Enterprise, you need to go through the Google Play Store, which is what I was hoping to avoid.